# Conditional Statements in youcanbook.me notifications body for more than one variable to test

Tags: if-statement, markdown, conditional-formatting

Youcanbook.me allows you to use conditional statements within the body of their notifications.

The basic format is:

`{IF}{xxx}{EQUALS}yyy{THEN}aaa{ENDIF}`

Their doc [mentions that they don't support logic operators AND/OR](https://support.youcanbook.me/article/99-make-your-booker-confirmation-email-specific-to-each-booking)

So the following is not possible:

`{IF}{xxx}{EQUALS}yyy{AND}{zzz}{EQUALS}aaa{THEN}bbb{ENDIF}`

and they don't seem to support nested IF statements neither. You can't do this:

```
{IF}{xxx}{EQUALS}yyy{THEN}
    {IF}{zzz}{EQUALS}aaa{THEN}
        bbb
    {ENDIF}
{ENDIF}
```

¿How, then, can you test for more that one variable? How to solve when you need to print something, say a link, based on a combination of 2 or more variables?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I know...

Concatenation

you can do something like this:

`{IF}{xxx}{zzz}{EQUALS}yyyaaa{THEN}bbb{ENDIF}`

That seems to work just fine.